How to decrypt Outlook 365 Email Messages in java spring boot
I am working in java and spring boot and using Microsoft Graph API now in outlook 365 encryption is enabled so now i want to know that how can i decrypt that email i am getting message.rpmsg
please respond as soon as possible
I have gone through the oficial documentation.But there is no guideline for this.
